# Log files are not generated by ear

Tags: file, logging

There are 2 ears V4 and V5 of same application. V5 is not generating logs but V4 is. What could be the reason. There is no difference in log4j.properties file between V4 and V5

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: There are 2 ears V4 and V5 of same application. V5 is not generating logs but V4 is. What is could be the reason. There is no difference in log4j.properties file between V4 and V5.